# cant set text in postExecute ,Async, Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am not able to find any appropriate solution for below issue. I am using  AsyncTask app sends request to server and it returns the JSON array as response, in postExecute method I parsed it, and **problem** is when I try to set the parsed data to TextView, textview not showing data. I am sure that server returned some data, and this data was parsed in postExecute and saved in global variables. TextViews also was declared as global variables, and defined in OnCreate method. thanks in advance! 
Please check Code mentioned below:

```
public class CompanyData extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button cComments;

    String ssid,bin;
    String extra, extra1;
    TextView compData1, compData2, compData3, compData4, compData5, compData6, compTitle;
    String title,  kod_okpo, address, reg_date, fio, kod_oked, ovd  ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_company_data);

        cComments = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cComment);
        cComments.setOnClickListener(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            extra = extras.getString("bin");
            extra1 = extras.getString("ssid");
            send_company_req(extra1, extra);
        }

        compTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.companyTitle);
        compData1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compData1);
        compData2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compData2);
        compData3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compData3);
        compData4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compData4);
        compData5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compData5);
        compData6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compData6);
        //Toast.makeText(this,"LOOOL" + title+bin+kod_okpo+address+reg_date+fio+kod_oked+ovd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cComment:
                Intent companyData = new Intent(CompanyData.this, Comments.class);
                companyData.putExtra("bin", bin);
                companyData.putExtra("ssid", ssid);
                startActivity(companyData);

                startActivity(new Intent(this, Comments.class));
                break;
        }
    }

    private void send_company_req(final String ssid, final String searchData) {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            String rStr;



            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(CompanyData.this, "Request...", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String token = params[0];
                String fi = params[1];
                String uri = Quickstart.URL + "/car/info";


                String param = null;

                try {
                    param = "ssid=" + URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8") +
                            "&bin=" + URLEncoder.encode(fi, "UTF-8") + "&dev=android";
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                    out.print(param);
                    out.close();
                    String response = "";
                    Scanner inStream = new Scanner(con.getInputStream());
                    while (inStream.hasNextLine()) {
                        response += (inStream.nextLine());
                    }

                    return response;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(CompanyData.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                JSONArray jsonArrayComp;



                try {

                    jsonArrayComp = new JSONArray(s.trim());


                    JSONObject jsonObjectComp = jsonArrayComp.getJSONObject(0);
                    try {



                        title = jsonObjectComp.getString("title");
                        kod_okpo = jsonObjectComp.getString("kod_okpo");
                        address = jsonObjectComp.getString("address");
                        reg_date = jsonObjectComp.getString("reg_date");
                        fio = jsonObjectComp.getString("fio");
                        kod_oked = jsonObjectComp.getString("kod_1_oked");
                        ovd = jsonObjectComp.getString("vidd");
                        Toast.makeText(CompanyData.this,"LOOOL" + title+bin+kod_okpo+address+reg_date+fio+kod_oked+ovd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    } catch (Exception ee) {

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Toast.makeText(CompanyData.this, "Упс,:( что то пошло не так, попробуйте еще раз пожалуйста.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


                compTitle.setText(title);
                compData1.setText(bin);
                compData2.setText(kod_okpo);
                compData3.setText(address);
                compData4.setText(reg_date);
                compData5.setText(fio);
                compData6.setText(kod_oked + " - " + ovd);

            }

        }

        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute(ssid, searchData);
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't initialising the `bin` string var anywhere.

Comment: Also, what do you mean exactly when your say "*cant set the parsed data to TextView*"? Do you run into any errors?

Comment: Try printing "s" [returned response] in console.

Comment: Shaishav, no errors, TextView shows the default value, not  value that I set

Comment: And you are getting the `LOOOL` toast with proper values?

Comment: VVB, I already checked response and parsed data, it shows right data

Comment: In your `onCreate()` move the textview allocation right after `setContentView` i.e. before you call `send_company_req()`. Also, tag me and other users in your comments as @<userName>.

Comment: How do you know there are no errors? Your catch blocks are empty...

Comment: Are you getting any exception check that by debug the app and also set text inside try block so you will get exact point of exception

Comment: @Shaishav, I did as you say , app crashed . 
Error is void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference. Does it mean that I should define TextViews in postExecute. about exceptions, app showed the Toast inside try block , which means  data parsed normally

Comment: @ cricket_007, I tested it, by putting Toast inside and outside try,catch blog.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that error there. At which line did the exception point to?

Comment: @Shaishav, at the line where starts setting the text(compTitle.setText(title);) Also , after this line it showed this line as the where is  error(class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {)

Comment: That means by that line the `compTitle` is not initialised. But, since you did initialise it before calling `send_company_req`, it could mean that the textview is not there in your layout.

Comment: @Shaishav, thanks a lot, you were right. Cause is I incorrectly initialized comTitle textview, in findViewById I put wrong id, and for this elementary error I spent many hours. Thanks!!

Comment: Its OK, it happens to the best of us :)